# Variable as Jquery selector invalid?

Tags: jquery

I currently have these lines of Jquery

```
var location = urlParams["location"]; //grabs URL parameter generated from earlier function
alert (location); // alerts the value WEST
alert ($("#" + location)); //returns [object Object]
var name = $("#" + location).attr("name").split(".");
alert (name); // no alert box appears
var css = name[0] + "px " + name[1] + "px";
$("#main-div").css("background-position",css)
alert ("Even this alert won't appear?");
```

The code runs against this HTML:

```
<a class="nav-links r1s1" id = "WEST" name="0.0" href="test.php?loc=WEST"></a>
```

No value is generated for name.  Later alerts won't even appear which leads me to believe there is something wrong with this line:

```
var name = $("#" + location).attr("name").split(".");
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You *could* have just edited the question instead of deleting and reposting, but this works too.

Comment: Most likely .attr("name") is not returning a string, making split undefined. Where is this code running? sounds like it's running before the anchor tag exists.

Comment: Is there any error message in the console?

Comment: try using console.log() instead of alert.. and have your developer tools console open

Comment: #wirey and @romainberger, I get TypeError: $(...).attr(...) is undefined

Comment: `location` in the global scope represents the [window's location object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.location) so trying to assign it an arbitrary value which isn't a valid URI will fail - you should use another var name or wrap it inside an IIFE. Didn't submit this as an answer 'cause there's apparently another problem with the split method..

Comment: Oh wait, you said it alerts `WEST` so that most likely isn't your problem.

Comment: This seems to work fine though: http://jsfiddle.net/d8mzK/ I've only put your code inside a DOM ready handler and commented out some alerts, also replaced `urlParams["location"]` by `WEST` for quick testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The modification to this line seemed to solve it.

```
 var location = String(urlParams["location"]);
```

Thanks all.

Answer (score -1):

I think depending on which part you want the first or second you would need to do this:

```
var name = $("#" + location).attr("name").split(".")[0];
```

or

```
var name = $("#" + location).attr("name").split(".")[1];
```

Comment: If he does not specify what part he wants, it will just alert an array, it would not create an error